# “sudo pip install frida –upgrade –ignore-installed six ” error How to solve the error

Tags: pip, frida

```
Password:
The directory '/Users/allin/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/allin/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Invalid requirement: '–upgrade'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 252, in from_line
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 97, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'\xe2\x80\x93upgra'"
```

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is

```
sudo pip install frida --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

i.e. use double minuses, not em/en-dashes. Do not blindly copy commands from web pages without understanding them.